# How to append a new value to an item within an array in Firebase?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, angularfire

Within Firebase, I have a list of 'ideas.' If a user presses a button associated with the idea, I'd like a value to be appended to that idea under an attribute called 'newValue.'

For example, the below html, uses ng-repeat to show the array of ideas and creates an associated button called 'Append Value.' I want a new value to be appended to the idea's attribute called 'newValue' every time a user presses 'Append Value.'

```
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <table>
  <tr class="item" ng-repeat="(id,item) in ideas">
    <td>{{item.idea}}</td>
    <td><input ng-model="newValue"></td>
    <td><button ng-click="ValueAppend(id,newValue)">Append Value</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Below is my attempt to create this function.

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["firebase"]);

app.factory("Ideas", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {
  var Ref = new Firebase('https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/');
  var childRef = Ref.child('ideas');
  return $firebase(childRef).$asArray();
}]);

app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope","Ideas", function($scope,Ideas) {
  $scope.ideas = Ideas;
  $scope.idea = "";

  $scope.ValueAppend = function (id,newValue) {   
    var URL = "https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/" + id + "newValue";
    var IdeaRef = new Firebase(URL);
    var IdeaData = $firebase(IdeaRef);
    $scope.IdeaAttributes = IdeaData.$asArray();
    $scope.IdeaAttributes.$add({
        newValue: newValue,
        timestamp: Date.now()
      });
  };

}]);
```

See my codepen for my working example: http://codepen.io/chriscruz/pen/PwZWKG

More Notes: 
I understnad that AngularFire provides $add() and $save() to modify this array, but how could I use these methods so that I can add a new 'string' under an item in an array.

Comment: The codepen is giving "ReferenceError: $firebase is not defined", because you're failing to inject it into the controller. After fixing that it seems to work, but you might be missing a slash before newValue in this URL: `var URL = "https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/" + id + "newValue";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if these are your problems, but they are two typoes of mistakes in the code above and the codepen: typos and conceptual.

### Typos

You forgot to inject `$firebase` into the controller, which leads to:

> "ReferenceError: $firebase is not defined"

Solution is simply of course:

```
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope","Ideas", "$firebase",  function($scope,Ideas,$firebase) {
```

In addition you seem to be missing a slash before `newValue`, which means that you're trying to create a new idea instead of adding the value to an existing one. Solution is simple again, add a slash before `newIdea` as in:

```
    var URL = "https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/" + id + "/newValue";
```

If you find yourself making this mistake more often, you might be better server by the `child` function. Although it typically is a bit more code, it lends itself less to this typo of typo. Creating the ref to the `newValue` node becomes:

```
    var URL = "https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/";
    var IdeaRef = new Firebase(URL).child(id).child("newValue");
```

### Conceptual

With those trivial typos out of the way, we can focus on the real problem: which is easiest to see if you console.log the URL that you generate:

> https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/0/newValue

Yet if you look up the same data in the Firebase forge (by going to https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/ in your browser), you'll see that the correct URL is:

> https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/-JbSSmv_rJufUKukdZ5c/newValue

That '0' that you're using comes from the `id` and it is the index of the idea in the AngularJS array. But it is not the `key` that Firebase uses for this idea. When AngularFire loads your data with `$asArray` it maps the Firebase keys to Angular indexes. We need to perform the reverse operation to write the new value to the idea: we need to map the array index (in `id`) back to the Firebase key. For that you can call `[$keyAt(id)][1]`. Since you keep the array of ideas in `Ideas`, it is simply:

```
    var URL = "https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/";
    var IdeaRef = new Firebase(URL).child(Ideas.$keyAt(id)).child("newValue");
```

So the controller now becomes:

```
app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope","Ideas", function($scope,Ideas) {
  $scope.ideas = Ideas;
  $scope.idea = "";

  $scope.ValueAppend = function (id,newValue) {   
    var URL = "https://crowdfluttr.firebaseio.com/ideas/";
    var IdeaRef = new Firebase(URL).child(Ideas.$keyAt(id)).child("newValue");
    var IdeaData = $firebase(IdeaRef);
    $scope.IdeaAttributes = IdeaData.$asArray();
    $scope.IdeaAttributes.$add({
        newValue: newValue,
        timestamp: Date.now()
      });
  };
}]);
```

I quickly gave it a spin in your codepen and this seems to work.