# AngularJS - Why can't I get my array length updated in real-time?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm populating a simple To-do notes application using `AngularJS` and `Firebase`. (And I'm new to AngularJS, too !) The To-do notes will be saved in `$scope.todos` variable. This is my `app.js` code:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $firebase) {
    // connect to firebase
    var ref = new Firebase("https://XXX.firebaseio.com/todos");
    var fb = $firebase(ref);
    $scope.todos = [];
    // sync as object
    var syncObject = fb.$asObject();
    // 3-way data binding
    syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "todos");

    $scope.addNewTodo = function(){
        var todoTitle = $(".add-todo").val();
        var createdAt = new Date();
        var element = {
            title: todoTitle,
            timestamp: createdAt,
            done: false
        };
        fb.$push(element);
        $(".add-todo").val("");
    };
});
```

And this is my `index.html` code:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="todolist not-done">
                <h1>Todos</h1>
                <input type="text" class="form-control add-todo" placeholder="Add todo" ng-enter="addNewTodo()">
                <button id="checkAll" class="btn btn-success">Mark all as done</button>
                <hr/>
                <ul id="sortable" class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="todo in todos">
                    <li class="ui-state-default">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value=""/> {{ todo.title }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="todo-footer">
                    <strong><span class="count-todos">{{ todos.length }}</span></strong> Items Left
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added `{{todos.length}}` for counting the remaining todos elements in the `$scope.todos` array. But it isn't automatically updated when I add or remove elements from the `$scope.todos` array. This is a bit strange for me cause it's quite different than what `MeteorJS` does, if I do the same thing.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Firebase but it looks to be Firebase related. In my test it's working: http://plnkr.co/edit/TmGu2V92rz4BrompD8Dx?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @unobf already said, you should use AngularFire's `$asArray` in this case.

Firebase loads (and synchronizes) your data asynchronously in the background. This means that it may receive updates to the array even when the current user wasn't the one who added a task. When this happens, it needs to (in addition to updating the array) notify AngularJS that the data was modified. You call `$asObject` which handles such notifications for objects, but was not designed to handle arrays. For handling the intricacies between Firebase's ordered collections (which don't use indexes, but a different type of keys) and AngularJS arrays, you need to use `$asArray`.

```
.controller('mainController', function($scope, $firebase) {
// connect to firebase
var ref = new Firebase("https://XXX.firebaseio.com/todos");
var fb = $firebase(ref);
$scope.todos = [];
// sync as object
var syncObject = fb.$asArray();
// 3-way data binding
$scope.todos = syncObject; // was: syncObject.$bindTo($scope, "todos");

$scope.addNewTodo = function(){
    var todoTitle = $(".add-todo").val();
    var createdAt = new Date();
    var element = {
        title: todoTitle,
        timestamp: createdAt,
        done: false
    };
    $scope.todos.$add(element);  // was: fb.$push(element);
    $(".add-todo").val("");
};
```

You can find a working example here: http://jsbin.com/celefu

To learn more about this type of problem, also see my answer to these questions:

- [Firebase binding not being reflected in Angular view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432740/firebase-binding-not-being-reflected-in-angular-view/27433610#27433610)
- [How to append a new value to an item within an array in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336228/how-to-append-a-new-value-to-an-item-within-an-array-in-firebase/27337679#27337679)
- [firebase get data for every child item's child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156491/firebase-get-data-for-every-child-items-child/27172348#27172348)
- [Asynchronous access to an array in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049342/asynchronous-access-to-an-array-in-firebase/27050749#27050749) (which includes links to even more answers that deal with this type of problem)

Comment: Thanks so much for your clear & deep answer ! Now my app works again :)

Comment: Also check out the [AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html), which covers most everything said here, albeit less eloquently.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you will want to use a Synchronized Array instead of the 3 way data binding https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays